# How to prevent randomly generated numbers from creating matching numbers

Tags: php, cookies, permissions, code-generation, media

I am in process of creating a media shop where when you purchase an item, it inserts random data into a cookie that is to be matched later for specific access to only those that purchase that item/media in that browser. Thus, if one user purchases an item, there will be one set number inserted for access rights, and one random number that gets inserted into the browsers cookies for location rights. Beforehand when they purchase the item, they will be told that if they try to access the media with a different browser or computer, they will be locked from accessing the media until they contact personnel for further direction. If the user tries to access the media without cookie code (random number) then they will generate a code that isn't accessible to their browser or any other browser. (locks access)

**My only concern is, what if the generator generates a random code twice, will that create conflict? and how do I prevent it?**

If this isn't going to work, because that is not the way cookies are used, then let me know now before I start, and please suggest another way I can code this while staying within the idea.

Thank you,

Any tips are welcomed.
 
If there is any way to do this better, I welcome suggestion.

Comment: Are you trying to restrict it by user or by browser/computer? It's much easier to block by user if you can

Comment: What happens when a user clears their cookies, or turns their cookies off? i think a database would be better suited for storage and as relentless mentions better to just restrict to user instead of medium. With the database you can just query to see if it was already generated and just regenerate a new one until you dont get one thats not already used.

Comment: You could use a unique id generator like [uniqid](http://www.php.net/uniqid) that is less likely to generate a collision.

Comment: I've been searching for ways to do so. I just don't want the media given to the user after purchase to be able to "share" the media. Hence, lock by location. How would I do this by user? just create another column for location access instead of cookie??

Comment: and by "share" I mean, give others their login information for access.

Comment: It sounds like you might be over thinking this. I'd build it so it grants the user access via username and password. I wouldn't worry about sharing. You're never going to stop it. Think about sites such as NetFlix. You have a username and password. In theory, anyone could use the account and watch a movie.

Comment: in that case, I may just abandon the idea or take it up again after I have the media running to see if I can do something else.

Answer (score 0):

first cookies is not the best idea and random number too to stay more friendly try to use an ip lock save the ip in an cookie with expiration date of the time of the location use a cookie and a mysql table try to do 2 table one stores the ipa like this 111.111.111,32 the number after the comma is a film id each film has its own id and for each film put another comma the id and for another film another comma and the id and do this each film and save the ids on a cookie and check the ids and check if the film id on the page matches with the ones in cookie and if the cookie matches with the mysql table is more secure and more friendly in case of the client needs to use other browser he can and if ip of the browser matches with the one in the mysql table then set a cookie on this browser I believe this can solve for you.
to avoid 2 identical tokens use this

```
<?php
$token = sha1(rand(1,999999));
$_Token = sha1($token);
$token = $_POST['filmid'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$cd = $ip, $token, $_Token;
setcookie("$token", $cd);
?>
```

and then put this data in a cookie with the ip